# Proxy timeout with ReWriteRule

Tags: apache, proxy, timeout

There is no way of controlling timeout when proxying by means of ReWriteRule (mod_rewrite) with Apache 2.4.

```
<VirtualHost "*:443">
  ServerName xxxx
  Use ssl
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*/wms|/openlayers3/.*) http://localhost:8080$1 [P,L]
  RewriteRule .* [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried unsuccessfully:

- `Timeout 400`
- `ProxyTimeout 400`
- ProxySet

```
<Proxy "http://localhost:8080/">
  ProxySet connectiontimeout=100 timeout=400
</Proxy>
```

- `ProxyPass "/" "http://localhost:8080" connectiontimeout=100 timeout=400`

The timeout is always 1 minute, no matter which of the above directives I use.

Comment: Can you show the log entry for the timeout you hit with some context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This timeout can be controlled [only globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31903273/2193305). Change the global `Timeout` setting in `httpd.conf` to your preferred value:

```
#
# Timeout: The number of seconds before receives and sends time out.
#
Timeout 400
```

Probably a better way to do this would be to use nginx:

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  xxxx;
    # ... ssl setup ...

    location ~* /wms$ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout 400;
    }

    location /openlayers3/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_read_timeout 400;
    }

    location / {
        return 403;
    }
}
```

Additional links to nginx documentation so that you understand what's going on in this snippet:

- [`location`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and how regular expressions work in nginx
- [`proxy_pass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)
- [`proxy_read_timeout`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout)
- [Converting rewrite rules](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html) from Apache to Nginx

For the SSL configuration missing in my snippet please also read [the documentation](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#example).

Comment: There is no global `Timeout` present in my Apache config files, except the one I placed.  It isn't honored.

Comment: @david.perez should be there: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: @david.perez but I really suggest just using Nginx. It's more powerful and reliable, it's fast, and you can easily configure it the way you want.

Comment: now I have the time to test nginx and it works better than apache, and syntax looks simpler, thanks.